# Wordpress Custom Rewrite Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom page template to use for a wordpress page. I am trying to setup a custom rewrite rule but without success.

I have a page at blog/book-page/, the display of this page depends on the book id, hence I want url like blog/book-page/book-id/ to read the book id.

In my functions php I have included the below function from Wordpress Codex:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^book-page/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=11&book_id=$matches[1]','top');
```

But when I access http://xyz.com/book-page/123/, it keeps on redirecting me to http://xyz.com/book-page/

I refreshed the rewrite rules by saving the permalinks in the dashboard.

Unable to solve by looking at similar questions at:
[Custom rewrite rule is not picked by Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70739/custom-rewrite-rule-is-not-picked-by-wordpress) and 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91673/need-help-creating-custom-rewrite-rule

Any suggestions, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in `functions.php` are you adding this rewrite rule?

Comment: using 
`add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
 
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
        $newrules = array();
        $newrules['(generate-photo-quotes)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]';
        return $newrules + $rules;
}`

Comment: Hmm, but you don't have this `book-page` rewrite rule in this code.

Comment: yes ... it should be '$newrules['(book-page)/(\d*)$']', but it still does not work.

Comment: Could you update your question so that it shows how your code looks exactly? In question you're using `add_rewrite_rule` function, in comment you're using `rewrite_rules_array` hook and different rule. It's hard to tell what's wrong with your code, when you're not showing it...

Answer (score 0):

The Yoast SEO wordpress plugin is the culprit in this case. It was redirecting all rewrite urls to the base url. You can turn it off in the plugin settings page.