# Wordpress query vars are not added

Tags: wp-query, query-variable

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get my custom url rewrites working ([WP Rewrite the last two parts of the URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133877/wp-rewrite-the-last-two-parts-of-the-url)), while doing this I came across the following problem:

I have made a custom plugin (OOP) and I'm trying to add query variables to the public wordpress query variables list.

The code I use is the following:

```
/**
     * Adding the trainingid var so that WP recognizes it, this is being called on the query_vars filter in the constructor.
     * @param $vars the variables coming from the filter
     * @return the same variables with the plugins query vars appended.
     */
    function my_insert_query_vars($vars)
    {
        // Push the query var id in the $vars array
        array_push($vars, 'trainingid');
        return $vars;
    }
```

But when I execute the following code via a shortcode on a page the array printed does not contain trainingid.

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I take it you have `add_filter('query_vars', 'my_insert_query_vars' );` (or the object-related variant) near your method? Have you made sure that filter is firing?

Comment: @NateCook It does fire, and when I print_r the $vars just before returning I see it added the variable to the array.